# Aligning FFT frames

Tags: audio, signal-processing, fft

I have 2 100% identical WAVE files I convert to FFT. Overlaying them I get a perfect match.

However if I chop off a non-frame sized chunk at the beginning of one of the data then the FFT's don't match (aligned from end).

I'm guessing that this is because of what frequencies are contained within the frame. If a frequency is divided amongst two frames it will show up with lower energy in both compared to if it was concentrated in one frame.

How can I compensate/bypass this effect?

Comment: You can't - an FFT is just a transformed representation of the input data - if you change the input data then you change the transformed representation of the data. Maybe it would be better if you explained what you are *really* trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm really trying to compare sound. And "you can't" is not how I will be solving this, though I sometimes get that response a lot before I find the answer. :)

Comment: You need to understand that the *features* of e.g. music are *time-varying*. If you want to characterise a song in the way that e.g. Shazam does, then you'll need to need to do a little more work than just taking FFTs, since this doesn't really reduce the total amount of *information* in the song. You need to find smart ways of reducing the amount of information to something which uniquely characterises the song in as few bytes as possible and which is unaffected by small changes caused by e.g. different compression levels, etc.

Comment: All the surroundnig stuff is already done and matching/comparison is working. I'm trying to achieve further improvement by overcoming the difference in "offset aligning" in the FFT. I imagine there are more or less standard ways of doing this in signal processing.

Answer (score 1):

The only exact way to do this is to IFFT your data (assuming a non-lossy initial window), then re-window it and re-FFT it using the new offset.  Might be better to just make a bunch of sets of FFT frames, each with a different initial offset.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to apply a window function before computing the FFT.

[http://www.google.com/search?q=windowing+fft](http://www.google.com/search?q=windowing%20fft)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform:

> "Using the DFT implies that the finite segment that is analyzed is one
>   period of an infinitely extended periodic signal; if this is not
>   actually true, a window function has to be used to reduce the
>   artifacts in the spectrum. "

I think you're on the right track breaking up the signal into overlapping frames but you need to consider your matching criteria (figure out some heuristics, e.g. the 3 dominant frequencies), the size of the frames (too small and you'll miss lower frequencies, too high and you have less resolution) etc.  Do some research, I'm sure many people have tackled this problem and [published papers](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=comparing%20audio%20identification%20signature%20fourier%20transform&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1,5&as_ylo=&as_vis=0).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect the result of the Fourier transform to be identical after you cut off part of one of the samples?  I'm not sure what you're trying to compensate for, that's expected behavior.

If you're comparing two samples to see how much they differ in "signature" then you probably want to normalize the result of your DFT.  Sum all the energy values in each frequency bin and then divide the value in each bin by that sum, so that the sum of all the energy in the result is 1.  Allows you to compare two different samples apples-to-apples regardless of length.

Note that this is only one, perhaps over-simplified, way of normalizing the DFT.  There are countless others.  Depending on your input data and what you plan to do with it, a log normalization might be better than a linear one.

Comment: I know it is expected behaviour. If the data changes, the FFT changes. But I need to compensate somehow. Would for example calculating avg of 3 frames (N=-1,0,1) work? I've been trying to understand overlapping frames for FFT, but all my attempts seem to either blur out the frequencies too much or cause mismatch.

Comment: But what are you trying to compensate *for*?  If you perform DFT on two audio samples that aren't identical, the results won't be identical.  There's no way to make them identical and still have a working DFT.  What are you trying to do with the DFT results?

Comment: I'm making an audio search engine/comparison engine. I'm identifying peak energy/hotspots for alignment. From what I can see the shift in FFT frames causes a significant difference (guessing ~10%) at 4096 byte frames, so some of the "hotspots" are different. This is caused by energy being divided differently between frames I guess. So I want to compensate for the different shift in frames.